# Django column wagtailcore_page.draft_title does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, wagtail

Django==1.11.3, wagtail==1.11.1

I did a backup of my PostgreSQL on remote server and did a restore on my local server so I can get an exact copy of all the changes.  I've done it this way for a long long time and its always worked like a charm.  But this time, I did the restore and got the error below:

`column wagtailcore_page.draft_title does not exist
LINE 1: ...ore_page"."numchild", "wagtailcore_page"."title", "wagtailco...`

I deleted my database and restored fresh but that did nothing. I deleted all migrations, did the `--fake` migration to try and reset, but nothing; still getting the error.  I am at a loss on this one and could use some feedback.  Thank you.

**Here's my trace file:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
['app',
 'home',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django_summernote',
 'rest_framework',
 'wagtail.contrib.settings',
 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
 'wagtail.wagtailcore',
 'wagtail.wagtailadmin',
 'wagtail.wagtaildocs',
 'wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
 'wagtail.wagtailusers',
 'wagtail.wagtailimages',
 'wagtail.wagtailembeds',
 'wagtail.wagtailsearch',
 'wagtail.wagtailsites',
 'wagtail.wagtailredirects',
 'wagtail.wagtailforms',
 'wagtail.contrib.wagtailsitemaps',
 'wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage',
 'wagtail.contrib.wagtailstyleguide',
 'wagtailmenus',
 'compressor',
 'taggit',
 'modelcluster',
 'docs',
 'wagtail.contrib.table_block']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column wagtailcore_page.draft_title does not exist
LINE 1: ...ore_page"."numchild", "wagtailcore_page"."title", "wagtailco...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  244.             response = middleware_method(request)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/middleware.py" in process_request
  20.             request.site = Site.find_for_request(request)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py" in find_for_request
  129.         return get_site_for_hostname(hostname, port)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailcore/sites.py" in get_site_for_hostname
  38.         'root_page'

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  250.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1118.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  886.             raise original_exception

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  876.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/rooster/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/envs/alpha_omega/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: column wagtailcore_page.draft_title does not exist
LINE 1: ...ore_page"."numchild", "wagtailcore_page"."title", "wagtailco...
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restoring your database backup, you need to run `./manage.py migrate`. `draft_title` was added in Wagtail 1.11, so presumably your backup is from a site running Wagtail 1.10 or earlier.

(Running `--fake` is the opposite of what you want... it tells Django *not* to run any of the outstanding migrations, including the one that adds the `draft_title` column.)

Answer (score 2):

the error is due to the fact that you have not migrated the newest version of wagtail. just run `python manage.py migrate` and when you see it running, this will appear:

```
Running migrations:
Rendering model states ... DONE
Applying 
wagtailcore.0040_page_draft_title 
... OK
```

rerun your project and you're done.